# Problema em checar números primos

Tags: c

Tenho que criar um vetor de números aleatórios num intervalo de 0 a 250, e mostrar quais são os primos. Este é o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,n[10];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        n[i]=rand()%250;
        printf("%d numero: %d\n",i,n[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (j=2; j<n[i]; j++) {
            if (n[i]%j==0) {}
            else
                printf("O numero %d e primo\n",n[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Tenho quase certeza que tem algo errado na hora de tirar o resto da divisão, mas não sei o que é.

Comment: Ola. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Tem quase a certeza que ha algo de errado, mas qual e efectivamente o erro? O que acontece? Nao verifica correctamente os primos? Da algum excepcao? Nos gostamos de ajudar e explicar, mas convem sabermos qual o erro.

Comment: O erro era que ele imprimia numeros que nao eram primos como primos, mas já resolveram aqui embaixo

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Tem dois problemas.

O primeiro é de desatenção, muito comum entre os programadores que não se acostumam usar chaves para definir bloco sempre. Veja este código:

```
    for (j=2; j<n[i]; j++) {
        if (n[i]%j==0) {
        } else {
            printf("O numero %d e primo\n",n[i]);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Faz mais sentido para você? Porque o código executa assim. Note que o `break` está fora do `if`. No seu código parece que sua intenção era colocar dentro dele. Mas como não tem chave, só a primeira linha do `else` é uma linha condicional. O `break` executa sempre, seja o `if` der verdadeiro ou falso.

Mas nada disto importa muito porque tem um erro maior.

O segundo problema é que a lógica está errada. Você tem que passar por todas as divisões para ter certeza se é primo ou não. Depois de passar por todas (fazer todo o `for`) dá para comparar e ver se o número é primo. Se todo o *loop* for executado sem sair forçadamente com `break` significa que ele conseguiu testar todas as divisões e nenhuma deu divisão exata. Esta é a definição do que é primo ou não.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, n[10];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        n[i] = rand() % 250;
        printf("%d numero: %d\n", i, n[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < n[i]; j++) {
            if (n[i] % j == 0) { //deu divisão exata então já sabemos que não é primo
                break; //se não é primo pode parar de verificar cada divisão
            }
        }
        if (n[i] == j) { //verifica se o loop executou por completo, aí é primo
            printf("O numero %d e primo\n", n[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HF3BVR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uapxdnmb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/PrimeInArray.c).

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou muito bem :)

Answer (score 3):

A razão do código não funcionar está muito bem explicada na resposta do `@Maniero`.

Porém, há alguns detalhes adicionais que podem ser melhorados:

1. Não é necessário dividir o número sendo testado por múltiplos de 2, pois nenhum par é primo além do número 2.
2. Alguns matemáticos consideram o número `1` como primo, porém a teoria aceita de fatoração não funciona dessa forma, portanto a maioria não inclui o `1` na lista de primos, sendo o `2` o primeiro.

Ajustei o código para funcionar dessa forma e imprimir o resultado também para os números que não são primos.

```c
int main(void) {
    int i, j, n[10];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        n[i] = rand()%250;
        printf("%d numero: %d\n", i, n[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (n[i] <= 1) {
            printf("O numero %d nao e primo\n", n[i]);
        } else if (n[i] == 2 || n[i] % 2 != 0) {
            for (j = 3; j < n[i]; j++) {
                if (n[i] % j == 0) {
                    printf("O numero %d e divisivel por %d\n", n[i], j);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (n[i] <= j) {
                printf("O numero %d e primo\n", n[i]);
            }
        } else {
            printf("O numero %d e divisivel por %d\n", n[i], 2);
        }
    }
}
```

### [Código no IdeOne](http://ideone.com/athDxF)

Answer (score 1):

Vejamos o seu código, na parte aonde você testa se `n[i]` é primo:

```c
        for (j=2; j<n[i]; j++) {
            if (n[i]%j==0) {}
            else
                printf("O numero %d e primo\n",n[i]);
                break;
        }
```

Vamos verficar o que acontece quando ele tenta testar se 6 é primo:

```
n[i] = 6, j = 2, 6 % 2 == 0, nada acontece
n[i] = 6, j = 3, 6 % 3 == 0, nada acontece
n[i] = 6, j = 4, 6 % 4 == 2, imprime "O numero 6 eh primo", break
```

Agora vamos fazer o mesmo com o número 5:

```
n[i] = 5, j = 2, 5 % 2 == 1, imprime "O numero 5 eh primo", break
```

Agora vamos verificar o número 2:

```
Não entra no laço, não imprime nada.
```

O que está acontecendo?

Ele mostra que é primo se `n[i]%j` for diferente de zero (ou seja, quando ele cai no `else`). Mas isso não significa que `n[i]` é primo, significa apenas que `j` não é um divisor de `n[i]`, e isso vai ocorrer na primeira iteração de cara com o 2 para todos os números ímpares maior ou iguais a 3.

Como arrumar isso?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,n[10];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        n[i]=rand()%250;
        printf("%d numero: %d\n",i,n[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {

        // ******** Início do trecho corrigido. ********
        int primo = 1; // Ou seja, é primo até provar o contrário.
        for (j=2; j<n[i]; j++) {
            if (n[i]%j==0) {
                // j é um divisor de n[i], então não é primo.
                primo = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Se terminou o laço sem achar nenhum divisor, então é primo
        if (primo) printf("O numero %d e primo\n",n[i]);
        // ******** Fim do trecho corrigido. ********

    }
}
```

Comment: Sua solução foi uma que eu descobri há pouco, valeu pela ajuda aí :D

Comment: @user20153 Se a minha solução é o que você procurava, não se esqueça de aceitar a minha resposta. :)

Answer (score 0):

Até 250 faz uma tabela ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int diff(const void *, const void *);

static int primo[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47,
      53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127,
      131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197,
      199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241};

int main(void) {
    srand(time(0));
    for (int numeroaleatorio = 250; numeroaleatorio > -1; numeroaleatorio--) {
        int *r = bsearch(&numeroaleatorio, primo,
              sizeof primo / sizeof *primo, sizeof *primo, diff);
        if (r) printf("%d 'e numero primo\n", numeroaleatorio);
        if (!numeroaleatorio) break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int diff(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;
    return *aa - *bb;
}
```